# Word count program

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio

So two problems:
1) when I get to the part where I am trying to count the lowest and highest all the >, <, and = are all coming up with red squiggles underneath them with the error message "operand types are incompatible("int*" and "int")"
and second
when I set break points I am finding that the words from my file are not even being put in strings, all my strings are blank. Please help!

```
#include <iostream>

#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

struct numStringOccurrences //this brings the words into the struct as a string form
{
string wordFromFile;
int numOccurrence;
};

int countOccurrences(numStringOccurrences strOcc[], int pos) //this counts how many times the words show up
{
int wordCounts = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
if (strOcc[i].wordFromFile == strOcc[pos].wordFromFile)
wordCounts++;
}
return wordCounts;
}

int main()
{
string inputFile, wordFromFile;
bool wordFound = false;
string wordArray[10000];
int numOccurrence[10000];
int currentLoc = 0;

cout << "Good day! What is the input file name?: " << endl;
cin >> inputFile;

// Open file.
ifstream file(inputFile.c_str());

how to do 

this counts the highest and lowest word count and outputs it.
for (int i = 0; i < currentLoc; i++)
{
if (wordArray[i] == wordFromFile)
{
numOccurrence[i]++;
wordFound = true;
break;
}


if (wordFound == false)
{
wordArray[currentLoc] = wordFromFile;
currentLoc++;
}
}

// counts the lowest and highest occurrences.
int highest = numOccurrence[0];
int lowest = numOccurrence[0];


for (int count = 0; count < numOccurrence; count++)

{

if (numOccurrence > highest);
{
highest = numOccurrence;
}
if (numOccurrence < lowest)
{
lowest = numOccurrence;
}
//Display the largest and smallest value of the array
cout << "The highest value in the array is: " << highest << "\nThe lowest value in the array is: " << lowest << endl;


system("Pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't have any code that reads from the file so it's not really surprising your array doesn't have any words in it.

Comment: As it stands, your code doesn't even compile, so any runtime behaviour is impossible. Please edit your question to include the bare minimal but complete code required to show the problem. See also the guidelines on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

First, numOccurence is type `int*` while highest and lowest are type `int`, which by default aren't comparable. This also applies for `count`.

Second, your strings, except for `inputfile` which received a user input, are empty not only because you didn't extract any data from your files, but also because in your first `for` loop the counter `i` is compared with `currentLoc` which was initialized in 0 and never changed, and because `0<0` is false, it doesn't enter.

Answer (score 0):

You never get any content from your ifstream file. What you do is only to open a stream between the program and the file. All stream operators(<<,>>,=,+=,etc) will work with your "file" variable now and an example way to do it is.

String word;
While (file >> word)
{    /*Already here you can do all your checks for the.        string that you need*/
}